# Java, How do I drop one single digit from a number (In order to perform a calculation on the rest of the number)?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out part of a Java assignment and I am lost on what to do. If anyone can help or guide me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

The user has to enter a six digit "ticket number". I am trying to figure out how to drop the last digit of the number that the user input and place it into it's own variable.

For instance:

Ticket Number: 123456

How do I drop the "6" to make the number "12345" and put the 6 in its own variable?

I tried using the \b to backspace the last digit after turning the input into a string, but that did not work. And I have realized that it would just delete the number anyway if it did work.

Once the last digit is dropped we have to do calculations to get a remainder... I'm not worried about that, I have found that described in our book, I just can't figure out how to drop the digit and put it by itself.

I am very new to Java (this is a Chapter 2 assignment) so please go easy on me!

Thank you everyone for your help. I appreciate it!

This is what I came up with and the code works:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TicketNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String ticketNumber;
        int Ticket, Remainder, lastDigit;

        ticketNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Enter the six digit ticket number",
            "Verify Ticket", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        Ticket = Integer.parseInt(ticketNumber) / 10;
        lastDigit = Integer.parseInt(ticketNumber) % 10;
        Remainder = Ticket % 7;
        boolean Valid = lastDigit == Remainder;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valid Ticket" + "\n" + Valid);
    }
}
```

Comment: `(int)(number / 10)` ?

Comment: and `number % 10` for the last digit

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what data type you are working with. If the value is a `String`, you can use the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method:

```
String ticket = "123456";
String allButLast = ticket.substring(0, ticket.length() - 1); // becomes "12345"
```

If it is an `int` value, you can use integer division:

```
int ticket = 123456;
int allButLast = ticket / 10; // truncates to 12345
```

If it's a `float` or `double`, you can divide by 10 and cast to an `int` or you can use [`Math.floor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29) to drop the fractional part after dividing by 10.

EDIT: Based on the edit to your question, you can do this:

```
public class TicketNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String ticketNumber;
        int ticket, prefix, remainder, lastDigit;

        ticketNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Enter the six digit ticket number",
            "Verify Ticket", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        ticket = Integer.parseInt(ticketNumber);
        prefix = ticket / 10;
        lastDigit = ticket % 10;
        remainder = prefix % 7;
        boolean valid = lastDigit == remainder;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valid Ticket" + "\n" + valid);
    }
}
```

Note that `Ticket`, etc. are not good Java variable names; they should start with lower-case letters (e.g., `ticket`). I made that change in my version of the code.

Note that the calculation can be written more tersely as:

```
boolean valid = (ticket % 10) == ((ticket / 10) % 7);
```

and you can eliminate the variables `prefix`, `remainder`, and `lastDigit`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my question to also ask how I put the dropped integer into a variable by itself. I have an idea as to what I need to do. I'm just unsure as how to get the ".6" (or whatever digit) into an integer. Do I Parse it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo operator `%` and division operator `/`

```
int number = 123456;
int remainder = 123456 % 10;
int newNumber = 123456 / 10;
System.out.println(newNumber); // output is 12345
System.out.println(remainder); // output is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int n=123456,m=n/10;
     System.out.println("Number = "+m);//your code
```

Your Output:-

```
Number = 12345
```

Comment: Saying not to ask questions like this, yet answering it, then asking for up votes, seems weird.